# How to convert email in HTML to text (and correctly wraps reply emails)?

Tags: bash, email

I wonder if there a utility which can convert email in HTML to text. The utilities like html2text are fine but they do not handle well wrapping of reply emails (i.e., emails with "> ").

For example,
the line like this:

```
> Email address internationalization provides for a much larger range of
characters than many current validation algorithms allow, such as all Unicode
```

Should be wrapped like this:

```
> Email address internationalization 
> provides for a much larger range of
> characters than many current validation 
> algorithms allow,
```

Comment: Emails from what exactly? An exported msg file from Outlook or what? Narrow it down a bit.

Comment: That wrapping would have to be defined in some argument as a maximum line length.